# Japanese text input not supported in Blender?

Tags: interface, customization, osx

I had the impression that Japanese text input was a supported feature, but I can't get input to work. Text remains in the Roman alphabet, whereas in other applications it converts as it is typed.

I can *paste* pre-converted Japanese text into Blender, but can't type it as I label items. I have confirmed this on OS X 10.6 with the [Kotoeri](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kotoeri) input method, as well as on 10.10 with [Google's IME](https://www.google.com/ime/).

*(At this stage I can't tell if it's an OS-specific issue or not, so if any Linux or Windows users can report your results I would appreciate it.)*

[image: Japanese text not converting - 日本語の変換が出来ません]

In the screen shot above, you can see the [あ] indicating Hiragana input is enabled. But Blender won't take it.

In Preferences enabling **Translate: New Data** Causes newly-added objects to have Japanese names (Instead of "Cube", yours will be named "立方体"). But there is no mention of direct input in Preferences. Seems strange that Blender can accept pasted text, but not typed text. Is text conversion while typing not supported?

[image: Enabling all options for Japanese]

Comment: This may be OSX specific. Windows uses IME, Linux uses XInput.

Comment: @ideasman42 Thanks for the input. :-) Does it work for you using either of those?

Comment: I don't use this personally, but as far as I know those are working.

Comment: @ideasman42 Thanks. I guess for now it remains an open question, and could be a Mac specific issue.